# Eigen-values of a matrix $P^{-1}AP$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **QUESTION:** If A and P be $2$ non-singular $n\times n$ matrices and $\lambda$ is the eigen-value of $A$, then show that $\lambda$ is also
>   the eigen-values of a matrix  $P^{-1}AP$.

I could simply show that $\lambda$ being the eigen-value of $A$, we have that 
$$det (A-\lambda I_n)=0$$

But I could not proceed further and make any comment on the question asked.

**NOTE:** I am **unaware** of *diagonalisation of matrices*, if at all it is playing any part in this problem. And also I require a method which **does not** utilise this principle of *diagonalisation* to solve this.

Comment: @Moo I know that. But the problem was given in a mathematics paper where the syllabus did not include diagonlisation. So surely, the examiner wants a solution *not* based on diagonlisation.

Answer (score 3):

Actually $A$ and $P^{-1}AP$ share the same characteristic polynomial, hence they have the same eigenvalues. Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\det(P^{-1}AP-\lambda I_n) & = \det(P^{-1}(A-\lambda I_n)P))\\
& = \det(P^{-1})\det(A-\lambda I_n)\det(P)\\
& = \det(A-\lambda I_n).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: How do you make that transformation $P^{-1}AP-\lambda I=P^{-1}(A-\lambda I)P$? I mean, $\lambda I$ contains no $P$, then how is it that you can factor out the $P$?

Comment: Do the distribution to get $P^{-1}AP - P^{-1}\lambda I P$. But the second term is clearly equal to $\lambda I$.

Answer (score 3):

It's just that $$P^{-1}AP-\lambda I=P^{-1}(A-\lambda I)P. $$

Comment: How do you make that transformation $P^{-1}AP-\lambda I=P^{-1}(A-\lambda I)P$? I mean, $\lambda I$ contains no $P$, then how is it that you can factor out the $P$?

Comment: $I=P^{-1}P. \ \ $